# Setting up JSP page to restart CentOS

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, centos

I am trying to create a jsp page under tomcat webserver to restart CentOS7 server. It is able to write a text file but unable to invoke restart/shutdown command. Is it due to permission issue?

```
<%
  Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
  Process proc = runtime.exec("reboot");
  out.println("restart");

%>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: *Is it due to permission issue* hopefuly

Comment: i have no idea. I am new to centos. I have tried to change my folder permission to 777

Comment: You should not open the possiblitiy to restart your Server by a JSP. It is a verry big security issue

Comment: i know is a big security issue but is part of my requirement. i am also trying to set ip address through JSP too but failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change the permission of tomcat.

https://www.shellhacks.com/how-to-grant-root-access-user-root-privileges-linux/